# create web service client from OIM 11g?

Tags: web-services, client

Can you suggest me how to deploy the spml webservice in OIM 11G, I have gone through the OIM 11G developers guide but I didn't find any thing related to deploying spml webservice in OIM 11G. 
I have a requirement on create & update user in OIM 11g from a spml message which comes from client application.
I will really appreciate if you could provide me steps on how to create web service client from OIM 11g Developer tool using WSDL. Is there any documentation on this chapter?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SPML service is already in OIM, you could use this service from client applications.
As you can see in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10391_01/doc.910/e10366/spml.htm): The SPML Web Service supports only inbound provisioning requests.

BTW, may be helpful example: http://blog.sbeynon.net/2011/06/oim-11g-spml-client-test.html